# Sharepoint Versions table

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql

I have a question about the table above, versions. The information in usernames is that the user who installed the update/roll up/first installation?

Kind Regards

Comment: emmm, about what " information in usernames" You are talking about?

Comment: In the table versions there is a column usernames. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh633284(v=office.12).aspx , UserName: A string containing the user name adding or updating the version. Is this the same as the user who is installing.

Comment: The only thing can say - is that it is not good idea to do something direct in SP MSSQL database. SP provides his Object Model to manipulate data

Comment: I know, we lost or there is no documentation about who did an update. Thats what i try to figure out.

Comment: I think You should look in ULS IIS logs or upgrade logs, there should be upgrade process details, if logs are not deleted

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057/en-us/?wa=wsignin1.0) , direct queries to the SharePoint database put you farm in un supported mode.

Yes, that table's column will tell you under which account last update installed. it will give you time stamp as well.

You can cross check with it Os security logs(i believe) or if you have any other auditing system.